# XSLT access different tag outside the for-each

Tags: xslt

I want to output a different tag(active ) value by a condition inside a for loop.but cant do from this approach.any suggestions??

Data:

```
    <ss>
    <identifier>
        <system>
            <value value="10" />
        </system>
        <system>
            <value value="15"/>
        </system>
        <system>
            <value value="789"/>
        </system>
    </identifier>
    <active value="123" />
</ss>
```

Xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL /Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="ss">
        <Patient
            xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
            <identifier>
                <xsl:for-each select="identifier/system/value">
                    <xsl:variable name="aa">
                        <xsl:if test="@value='10'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="active/@value" />
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <gender value="{$aa}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </identifier>
        </Patient>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:
output that I expect from above code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Patient
    xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
    <identifier>
        <gender value="123"/>
        <gender value=""/>
        <gender value=""/>
    </identifier>
</Patient>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you want, to make it relative to the current `value` node is this

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../../active/@value" />
```

Alternatively, you could use an absolute expression

```
<xsl:value-of select="/ss/active/@value" />
```

Alternatively, use a variable to store it outside the `xsl:for-each`. For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="ss">
  <xsl:variable name="active" select="active/@value" />
  <Patient xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
    <identifier>
      <xsl:for-each select="identifier/system/value">
        <xsl:variable name="aa">
          <xsl:if test="@value='10'">
            <xsl:value-of select="$active" />
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>    
        <gender value="{$aa}"/>         
      </xsl:for-each>        
    </identifier>
  </Patient>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```